# Transmit and Receive message using GMSK/MSK modulation simulation

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

I'm trying to simulate the transmit and receive of a simple message (like "Helloworld") using an MSK/GMSK modulation but I seem to have some trouble receiving the message. I used the relatively new Symbol Sync block but I seem to be unable to get my input and output signals to align. I'm guessing I haven't set the Symbol Sync parameters properly. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that? (See below for flowgraph and current output)

I would like to eventually be able to implement this using USRP but am trying to simulate it first. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
[image: TX/RX MSK Flowgraph]
[image: Signal Inputs and Outputs]

Comment: please tidy up your flow graph – there's no reason these blocks aren't in nice straigh lines like your File Source – Throttle – Unpack! (there's even a command when you right click a group of blocks to align them) An easier-to-understand flow graph makes it easier to understand the question and hence easier to answer :)

Comment: GMSK mode is deprecated, right? Which version of GNU Radio are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that. I cleaned and organized the flowgraph and removed the LDPC blocks because I thought they might be redundant. Hopefully its easier to follow now. I'm using the latest gnuradio 3.9.5.0

Comment: The GMSK blocks that are available are GMSK Mod, GMSK Demod, and GMSK Modulator. They don't seem to be deprecated. Do I need to use a different set of GMSK blocks to get this to work?